# Return a list of all pairs row/column if condition of cell value is met

Tags: google-sheets

Given a Google Sheet table similar to the following:

```
  +---+---A--+---B--+---C--+---D--+
  | 1 |      | col1 | col2 | col3 |
  |---+------+------+------+------+
  | 2 | row1 |    1 |  X   |   45 |
  | 3 | row2 |    5 |      |      |
  | 4 | row3 |    4 |      |   34 |
  +---+------+------+------+------+
```

where row1, col1 are header labels and "X" is also a valid value for the combination "row/column";

I need to retrieve a list of all the possible combinations row/column headers that are not null, meaning in this example:

```
row1 | col1
row2 | col1
row3 | col1
row1 | col2
row1 | col3
row3 | col3
```

I tried in different ways such as using the ISBLANK function or the QUERY one as:

```
=QUERY(A1:D4, "SELECT A,B,C,D WHERE B IS NOT NULL OR C IS NOT NULL OR D IS NOT NULL",1)
```

but is simply a subset of the precedent table AND I cannot GROUP BY because there's no aggregate function;

Comment: can you provide a larger sample/example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a spreadsheet with 3 sheets, "Main", "LabelTable", and "List".

"Main" contains the data:

```
+---+---A--+---B--+---C--+---D--+
| 1 |      | col1 | col2 | col3 |
|---+------+------+------+------+
| 2 | row1 |    1 |  X   |   45 |
| 3 | row2 |    5 |      |      |
| 4 | row3 |    4 |      |   34 |
+---+------+------+------+------+
```

A named range from A2:D4 is created and named "Data".

My solution was to first make an accompanying table on "LabelTable" of the form:

```
+-------+---A--+------B-----+------C-----+------D-----+
|  1    |      |    col1    |    col2    |    col3    |
|-------+------+------------+------------+------------+
|  2    | row1 | row1 col1; | row1 col2; | row1 col3; |
|  3    | row2 | row2 col1; | row2 col2; | row2 col3; |
|  4    | row3 | row3 col1; | row3 col2; | row3 col3; |
+-------+------+------------+------------+------------+
```

where the number of rows and columns matches the size of the table on "Main".

If you have a large table, you can easily generate these by using the formula in B2 as `=$A2&","&B$1&";"` and copying across and down to the bottom right of your required range.

I then created a named range "Labels" from B2:D4 (or for larger tables, the full extent of the contents of this table)

On "List", I then entered the formula:

```
=transpose(split(concatenate(arrayformula(if(not(ISBLANK(Data)),Labels,""))),";"))
```

This produces a list of pairs, like "Row1Col1", corresponding to every value that is not blank.

**Description**

This uses `ISBLANK()` to determine if a cell is null or not. In combination with `ARRAYFORMULA()` on the "outside" this creates a table of TRUE or FALSE values.  It then wraps the TRUE/FALSE table with `IF()` to create a table of labels corresponding to where the TRUE/FALSE table has TRUE. This is where the named range "Labels" comes in - it provides the cell reference of where there was not a null value.

All of this is then wrapped in `CONCATENATE()` to give a single cell with the references joined.  Then `SPLIT()` is used to turn this into an array - and this is also why ";" was added into the cell references in "Labels".  Finally, `TRANSPOSE()` is used to turn the `1xN` array into an `Nx1` array, i.e., a single column.

**Limitations**

If you have a dynamic table then you'll need to also make "Labels" dynamic to match.  This method does not do that.

If for some reason there is a requirement that means you can't have the accompanying table on "LabelTable" then this method will not work. Some more will need to be done to "build that in" to the formula.